# Is giving gifts or money to a rich person regarded as Sadaqah?

Tags: hadith-interpretation, sadaqah

The following hadith says:

> Abu Hurairah (May Allah be pleased with him) said:
>
> The Messenger of
> Allah (ﷺ) said: "A man (from amongst the people before you) said:
> 'Indeed! I will give in charity.' So he took his Sadaqah out and
> placed it in a thief's hand.
>
> In the morning the people were talking
> (about this incident) and saying: 'Sadaqah was given to a thief last
> night.' The man said: 'O Allah! Praise be to You. I have given Sadaqah
> to a thief. Indeed, I will give in charity!' So he took his Sadaqah
> out and he placed it in a prostitute's hand.
>
> In the morning the people
> were talking (about this incident) and saying: 'Sadaqah was given to a
> prostitute last night.' On hearing this, the man said: 'Praise be to
> You, O Allah! I gave Sadaqah to a prostitute.
>
> Indeed, I will give in
> charity!' So he took his Sadaqah out and placed it in a rich man's
> hand. In the morning the people were talking (about this incident) and
> saying: 'Sadaqah was given to a rich man last night.' The man said: 'O
> Allah! Praise be to You (for helping me) give charity to a thief, a
> prostitute and a rich man.'
>
> Then he had a dream in which he was told
> that his Sadaqah to the thief might result in his refraining from his
> theft, his Sadaqah to the prostitute might help her abstain from her
> immorality, and his Sadaqah to the rich man might help him pay heed
> and spend from what Allah had bestowed upon him."
>
> [[Al- Bukhari]](https://sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/19/58).

This hadith seems to imply that giving money to a rich person is sadaqah. However, it is unclear if this rule apply to the Ummah because it may be a story about people of other prophets (the rules revealed to other prophets don't apply to us). Is giving gifts or money to a rich person regarded as Sadaqah?

Comment: Imam Malik considered the shari'a of former nations as our shari'a as long as it was not clearly abrogated.

Answer (score 1):

Whether gifts or money given to a rich person are regarded as sadaqah depends on the intention of the bestower, as it may have been given to seek Allah's pleasure, or to show love and strengthen friendship, or for some worldly reason.

What this hadith implies  is that:

- It is permissible to give non-obligatory charity to a rich person. Agreement has been claimed on on this.

  > تحل صدقة التطوع للأغنياء بلا خلاف فيجوز دفعها إليهم ويثاب دافعها عليها ولكن المحتاج أفضل
  >
  > It is permissible to give voluntary charity to rich people, and there is no difference of scholarly opinion on that. It is permissible to give it to them and the giver will be rewarded for it, but it is better to give it to one who needs it.
  >
  > <sup>— [al-Majmoo'](https://shamela.ws/book/2186/3151#p1) translation from [islamqa](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/82673/i) ; also see [مغني المحتاج](https://archive.org/stream/WAQ44502/mmmmam3#page/n157/mode/2up) and  [كشاف القناع](https://shamela.ws/book/21642/802#p5) and [بدائع الصنائع](https://shamela.ws/book/8183/370#p6)</sup>
- Charity given by mistake to an unintended or invalid recipient will still receive reward according to the intention behind the act. Bukhari has also narrated another hadith in a similar context:

  > #### لك ما نويت يا يزيد، ولك ما أخذت يا معن
  >
  > O Yazid, you have what you intended, and O Ma'n for you is what you took.
  >
  > <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/24/26)</sup>

As for the rules revealed to other prophets not applying to us, note that the view of the majority is that established laws of former nations are applicable to us when they have not been explicitly abrogated.

> #### أولئك الذين هدى الله فبهداهم اقتده
>
> Those are the ones whom Allah has guided, so from their guidance take an example.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 6:90](http://quran.com/6/90)</sup>

See my answer here: [Is there a concrete reason that Qur'an 5:32 (which prohibits murder) applies to modern-day Muslims?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/46551/)

Answer (score -1):

Well, the above hadith from bukhari has been misinterpreted alot, we have to go to hadith if we do not understand quranic verse, In Surah Tawbah ([9:60](https://corpus.quran.com/wordbyword.jsp?chapter=9&verse=60)) Its clearly mentioned that SADAQAAT can be ONLY given to so and so, the word here used is SADAQAAT (all Kind of Charities); if the verse had the word SADAQA then it would have been prominent sadaqa called Zakat.

Coming towards the Hadith, its not very clear what was the context of Hadith that Muhammad Rasool-Allah ﷺ is allowing us to give charity to wrong people (Thief, Prostitute and Rich who does not do charity) by telling a story of a person of previous Ummah OR is he telling us that if mistakenly you have given charity to wrong person still you will get the reward? So its not very clear, and this Hadith itself can be interpreted in may-be more logical ways, out of which I have mentioned the two. So we do have Surah Tawbah ([9:60](https://corpus.quran.com/wordbyword.jsp?chapter=9&verse=60)) in which Allah subhanawataala openly and clearly says that rich person is not in the list of taking any kind of SADAQAAT. Wallah o AAlim.
May Allah help us follow our deen and Quran the glorious.

Comment: al-Sadaqat in the Quran means obligatory charity i.e. zakat. This is the charity which is taken and distributed by the state and regarding which people complained to the prophet, see the context of the verse [9:58-60](https://quran.com/9/58-60)